# Using apache Spark to union to Lists of Tuples

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm attempting to union to RDD's :

```
val u1 = sc.parallelize(List ( ("a" , (1,2)) , ("b" , (1,2))))
val u2 = sc.parallelize(List ( ("a" , ("3")) , ("b" , (2))))
```

I receive error :

```
 scala> u1 union u2
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Any)]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Int, Int))]
Note: (String, Any) >: (String, (Int, Int)), but class RDD is invariant in type
T.
You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)
              u1 union u2
                       ^
```

The String type in each of above Tuples is a key.

Is it possible to union these two types ?

Once u1 and u2 are unioned I intent to use groupBy to group each item according to its key.

Comment: Do you really mean `("a" , ("3"))`  or should it be `("a" , (3))`? Also, do you really need tuples as values? Given Tuple1, and Tuple2 are different types, the group will be of the supertype `Any`

Comment: @maasg "do you really need tuples as values ?" Not necessarily, are you suggesting store the values in an object of type Any ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are facing is actually explained by the compiler:  You are trying to join values of type `(Int,Int)` with values of type `Any`. The `Any` comes as the superclass of `String` and `Int` in this statement: `sc.parallelize(List ( ("a" , ("3")) , ("b" , (2))))`. This might be an error or might be intended.

In any case, I would try to make the values converge to a common type before the union.
Given that Tuple1, Tuple2 are different types, I'd consider some other container that is easier to transform.

Assuming that the `"3"` above is actually a `3` (`Int`):

```
val au1 = sc.parallelize(List ( ("a" , Array(1,2)) , ("b" , Array(1,2))))
val au2 = sc.parallelize(List ( ("a" , Array(3)) , ("b" , Array(2))))
au1 union au2
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[Int])] = UnionRDD[10] at union at <console>:17
res: Array[(String, Array[Int])] = Array((a,Array(1, 2)), (b,Array(1, 2)), (a,Array(3)), (b,Array(2)))
```

> Once u1 and u2 are unioned I intent to use groupBy to group each item
>   according to its key.

If you intend to group both rdds by key, you may consider using `join` instead of `union`. That gets the job done at once

```
au1 join au2
res: Array[(String, (Array[Int], Array[Int]))] = Array((a,(Array(1, 2),Array(3))), (b,(Array(1, 2),Array(2))))
```

If the `"3"` above is actually a `"3"` (`String`): I'd consider to map the values first to a common type. Either all strings or all ints. It will make the data easier to manipulate than having `Any` as type. Your life will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an (key,value) RDD with any value (I see you are trying and RDD with and (Int,Int), and Int and a String), you can define the type of your RDD on creation:

```
val u1:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Any)] = sc.parallelize(List ( ("a" , (1,2)) , ("b" , (1,2))))
val u2org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Any)] = sc.parallelize(List ( ("a" , ("3")) , ("b" , (2))))
```

Then the union will work because it's the union between the same types.

Hope it helps